# ¿Como puedo poner una clase JPanel en un JIntercalFrame?

Tags: java, netbeans, poo, diseño-de-clases

he creado varias clases JPanel y ahora quiero mostrarlos en un JDesktopPane, pero en el JDesktopPane no se puede abrir un JPanel ¿o si ? Por lo que se me ocurre llamar a la clase JPanel desde un JInternalFrame y luego llamar el JInternalFrame para mostrarlo en JDesktopPane. Por favor necesito ayuda.

Comment: Intente esto, sin embargo me mostro el JinternalFrame sin nada. ----------
NewJInternalFrame= new NewJInternalFrame();
        if(NewJInternalFrame.isVisible()==false){
           
JPanel1 p= new JPanel1();
NewJInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(p);
jDesktopPane1.add(NewJInternalFrame);
NewJInternalFrame.setVisible(true);
        
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que veo para que no se muestre el `JInternalFrame` es que no le hayas establecido un tamaño, de lo contrario tendrá un **tamaño por defecto de 0,0**

---

**Te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo.**

```
public class PruebaInternalFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PruebaInternalFrame();
    }

    /**
     * Crea el JFrame, el JDesktopPane, un JInternalFrame 
     * de muestra y lo visualiza.
     */
    public PruebaInternalFrame() {
        // El JFrame con el JDesktopPane
        JFrame v = new JFrame("Prueba JInternalFrame");
        JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane();
        v.getContentPane().add(dp);

        // Se construye el panel que irá dentro del JInternalFrame
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JLabel("Etiqueta"));
        p.add(new JTextField(10));

        // Se construye el JInternalFrame
        JInternalFrame internal = new JInternalFrame("Un Internal Frame");
        internal.add(p);

        // Es importante darle tamaño -pack()- al JInternalFrame,
        // porque si no, tendrá tamaño 0,0 y no lo veremos.
        //internal.pack();
        internal.setSize(300, 200);

        // Por defecto el JInternalFrame no es redimensionable
        // tiene el botón de cerrar, así que se lo ponemos.
        internal.setResizable(true);
        internal.setClosable(true);

        // Se mete el internal en el JDesktopPane
        dp.add(internal);

        // Se visualiza todo.
        v.setBounds(200,200, 500,500);
        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        v.setVisible(true);

        // Se visualiza el JInternalFrame
        internal.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente:
[Ejemplo sencillo con JInternalFrame](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplo_sencillo_con_JInternalFrame)

Comment: Gracias me sirvió el código, y si era por el SetSize.